# VB.NET: How to compare different generic lists

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, generic-list

I have a method where I'm taking a generic object and using `TypeOf` to check what has been passed through. Now I would like to pass it a `List(Of T)` (T being anything) and no matter what T is I'd like to do the same thing to this list. I tried the following:

```
public sub foo(ByVal obj As Object)
    if TypeOf obj Is List(Of Object) Then
         'do stuff
    end if
end sub
```

but this doesn't seem to work if I pass it `List(Of String)`, say. I suppose that `List(Of Object)` and `List(Of String)` are being treated as different objects, but I thought that since `String` is an object, the comparision might work.

Now I realise that this is as ugly as sin and I'm better off overloading the method to take `List(Of T)` as its parameter, but I'm mostly asking out of curiosity: is there a way of comparing the types `List(Of Object1)` and `List(Of Object2)` and getting a positive result, since they are both just `List(Of T)`?

Comment: Uh, if the lists contain *different* types, how do you propose to compare them? I don't understand what's wrong with taking advantage of generics and accepting `List(Of T)`.

Comment: "no matter what T is I'd like to do the same thing to this list" - what is that thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List(Of Object)` and `List(Of String)` *are* different types. You can do different things with them - for example, you can't add a `Button` to a `List(Of String)`.

If you're using .NET 4, you might want to consider checking against `IEnumerable(Of Object)` instead - then generic covariance will help you.

Do you have any reason not to just make `Foo` generic itself?

Comment: @jon-skeet No reason not to make it generic (and that's what I have done). So `List(Of String)` and `List(Of Object)` are different types, but they are still both `List(Of T)`. Is `List(Of T)` some sort of type blueprint then?

Comment: Since you're proposing `IEnumerable(Of Object)` -- why not simply use the non-generic `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @geekchic: Yes, sort of. It's hard to describe a huge feature like generics in comments - I'd *strongly* suggest reading MSDN carefully or getting a good book.

Comment: @stakx: Yes, `IEnumerable` is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

To check if an object is of type `List(of T)` no matter of what type T is, you can use `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` as in the following example:

```
Public Sub Foo(obj As Object)
    If IsGenericList(obj) Then
        ...
    End If
End Sub    

...

Private Function IsGenericList(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
    Return obj.GetType().IsGenericType _
           AndAlso _
           obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() = GetType(List(Of ))
End Function
```

Or alternatively as an extension method:

```
Public Sub Foo(obj As Object)
    If obj.IsGenericList() Then
        ...
    End If
End Sub

...

Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module ObjectExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsGenericList(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return obj.GetType().IsGenericType _
           AndAlso _
           obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() = GetType(List(Of ))
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish. I'm pretty bad at mind reading, so I thought I'd let a few others try answering this question first. It looks like their solutions haven't been the silver bullet you're looking for, so I thought I'd give it a whack.

I suspect that this is actually the syntax you're looking for:

```
Public Sub Foo(Of T)(ByVal myList As List(Of T))
    ' Do stuff
End Sub
```

This makes `Foo` into a *generic method*, and  ensures that the object you pass in as an argument (in this case, `myList`) is always a generic list (`List(Of T)`). You can call any method implemented by a `List(Of T)` on the `myList` parameter, because it's guaranteed to be the proper type. There's really no need for anything as complicated as Reflection.